# FQL friend table return a lot of stranger name - "Facebook User"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

The Fql is (filter by name easy for you to see all of them at a glance):

> SELECT id,name,pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM
>   friend WHERE uid1=me()) and name='Facebook User'

Screenshot:

[image]

It's frustrating if my app show all of this **non-existed**/confusing name to my app user. The user id even **cannot be access via http://www.facebook.com/USER_I**D. The pic_square also is a facebook default profile picture. Of course, what i can do now is filter by **name!='Facebook User'**, but i really wonder why l have to do this extra filter?

Originally i wonder they are the user who has been removed/deactivated cached user. So i try to deactivated/or turn platform off a user to test, the user wouldn't appear as "Facebook User", he just doesn't appear at all. So the cause shouldn't related to privacy setting or account removed.

Also, i noticed the "Facebook User" issues long time ago, so there's no reason it's related to the cache.

This user ids wouldn't include via https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends. It just happen on FQL friend table.

I'm not sure it's a bug or not, may be i miss some conceptual about the friend table, so i ask the question here. **The stranger name "Facebook User" return from FQL friend table, whom is them?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a bug, I filed it for you at

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/555447487827125

you can subscribe to follow it.